# CSS :before and :after not working?

Tags: css

I am trying to use `:before` and `:after` with list but it is not working.
I am sure it's a simple mistake but I am not able to point it out.

Any help would be appreciated

Please check the [fiddle](http://Please%20check%20the%20[fiddle][1])

```
<div class="org-chart">
  <ul class="chart chart-prhead">
    <li>
      <span><a href="#">Dabba</a></span>
      <ul class="chart-mgr">
        <li>
          <!-- level 2 -->
          <span><a href="#">Dabba</a></span>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.chart ul:after {
  border: 1px solid #f30;
}
.chart li span:after {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.chart li span:before {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.chart li a:after {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
.chart li a:before {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: Your link is broken, but it looks like you have no `content` and no styling to make them large enough to have borders. You might actually want `border-left` and `border-right`.

Comment: I have voted to repoen, I had an issue that was not covered by the duplicate question. I think this question is open, the other only has to do with "content"

Answer (score 227, accepted):

If you want `:before` and `:after` to work, you need to give them `content`, otherwise they don't really 'exist'. The easiest thing to do is, in the css, set `content: ''` for both pseudoelements.

Comment: You should use also `display: block` to make it work with `content:''`

Comment: Also, you need to make sure `position: relative` is set to the element.

Comment: @WaltyYeung You do not

Answer (score 26):

You should use `:before` and `:after` selectors with `content` property:

```
.chart ul:after{
  content: "";
  border:1px solid #f30;
}
```